# How to Setup NativeControls in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm building another application for iOS and this time I would like to go more native with PhoneGap, so I saw [NativeControls](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/NativeControls/) and I loved the plugin features, but how do I get it setup on a Xcode 4 project? I haven't seen any tutorials about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you must reference the NativeControls.js file in your html page after including it in the www folder. Make sure that this file is located AFTER the phonegap.js file in your html. Next, add the .m & .h files in the plugins folder. Last, add NativeControls as a key in the phonegap.plist file, setting value as string. Also keep in mind this plugin only works for the iPhone.

You may also try checking out http://hiediutley.com/2011/03/30/phonegap-tutorial-series-%E2%80%93-5-third-party-plugins-nativecontrols/

Comment: I've done everything as above but I'm still not getting the tab bar. Could you provide some help?

Comment: Posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035821/phonegap-nativecontrols-not-working with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Include `NativeControls.js` in www folder, and `NativeControls.h` and `NativeControls.m` files in Plugins folder in Project. In the Cordova plist file add a key value pair under the item called 'Plugins' as 'NativeControls' (key name and value: NativeControls).

If you are using Native Controls for tab bar, place the following in the `onDeviceReady function`:

```
nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
nativeControls.createTabBar();

// First tab
nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
  "tab1",
  "Tab1",   //Name that appears on tab item
  "....png", //Tab image placed in Resources folder
  { "onSelect": function() {}}
);

// Second tab
nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
  "tab2",
  "Tab2",
  "....png", //Tab image placed in Resources folder
  { "onSelect": function() {}}
);

// Third tab
nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
  "tab3",
  "Tab3",
  "....png", //Tab image placed in Resources folder
  { "onSelect": function() {}}
);

// Compile the TabBar
nativeControls.showTabBar();
nativeControls.showTabBarItems("tab1", "tab2", "tab3");
nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("books");
```