# Phonegap NativeControls not working

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've read and followed tutorials on this site or the web on how to add the NativeControls plugin to PhoneGap (Cordova 1.5) with Jquery Mobile. I haven't been able to get the toolbar to work properly.

I've tried many different things with no luck. Here is my code:

html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no;" />-->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css"/>
  <script src="jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
  <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
  <title></title>  

    <!-- iPad/iPhone specific css below, add after your main css >
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 1024px)" href="ipad.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" href="iphone.css" type="text/css" />-->        

    <!-- If your application is targeting iOS BEFORE 4.0 you MUST put json2.js from http://www.JSON.org/json2.js into your www directory and include it here -->
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.5.0.js"></script>
    <script src="NativeControls.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
    <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
      <div data-role="page" id="mainpage"> 
          <div data-role="header">
              <h1>LOGIN</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
            <img src="images/cslogosmall2.png" style="margin-top: -10px; margin-left: -5px;"/>
            <form id="login" method="post">
              <p>
              <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="g" id="contentlist">
                  <b>Program:</b>
                  <input type="text" id="program"/>
                  <b>Username:</b>
                  <input type="text" id="username"/>
                  <b>Password:</b>
                  <input type="password"  id="password"/>
              </ul>
              </p>
              <br/>
                <button type="submit" data-theme="a" id="submit" value="Submit"></button>
            </form>
          </div>
          <!--<div data-role="footer"> 
              <h1> Main Page Footer </h1>
          </div>-->
      </div>
      <div data-role="page" id="contentpage"> 
          <div data-role="header"> 
              <h1> Content Page </h1>

          </div>
          <div data-role="content">
              <a href="#" data-role="button" onclick="history.go(-1);return false;" onClick=buttonDemo()> Back to Main Page </a>
              <a href="#" data-role="button" id="beepbtn" onClick=beepbeep()> Beep!</a>
          </div>
          <div data-role="footer"> 
              <h1> Content Page Footer </h1>
          </div>
      </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
function onBodyLoad()
{       
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var program = document.getElementById('program').value;
        var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
        var password = document.getElementById('password').value;

        if (!program || program == "") {
            alert("Please enter a program");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!username || username == "") {
            alert("Please enter a username");
            return false;
        }
        else if (!password || password == "") {
            alert("Please enter a password");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
}

/* When this function is called, Cordova has been initialized and is ready to roll */
/* If you are supporting your own protocol, the var invokeString will contain any arguments to the app launch.
 see http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html
 for more details -jm */
function onDeviceReady() {
  // Initializating TabBar
  navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is working");

  nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
  navigator.notification.alert(nativeControls);
  nativeControls.createTabBar();

  // Books tab
  nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
    "books",
    "Books",
    //"/www/tabs/book.png",
    "",
    {"onSelect": function() {
      books();
    }}
  );

  // Stats tab
  nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
    "finished",
    "Finished",
    //"/www/tabs/box.png",
    "",
    {"onSelect": function() {
      finished();
    }}
  );

  // About tab
  nativeControls.createTabBarItem(
    "about",
    "About",
    //"/www/tabs/info.png",
    "",
    {"onSelect": function() {
      about();
    }}
  );

  // Compile the TabBar
  nativeControls.showTabBar();
  nativeControls.showTabBarItems("books", "finished", "about");
  nativeControls.selectTabBarItem("books");
}


function books() {


}

function about() {

}

function finished(){

}
```

As you can see, I do a:

```
  navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is working");
  nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
  navigator.notification.alert(nativeControls);
  nativeControls.createTabBar();
```

to test if nativeControls variable has anything in it. I don't get any alerts.
I even tried:

```
navigator.notification.alert(window);
```

with no luck. I've added the NativeControls key to Cordova.plist as 
NativeControls - NativeControls.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

I uploaded the source code to my jQM App on the iTunes' store that has an example of the Tabbar working on both the iPhone and iPad, in both orientations. I hope it helps!!

http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/04/nativecontrols-plugin-for-cordovaphonegap/

Answer (score 4):

I also suffered the same struggle. There might be some misunderstanding on the constructor.

I saw [a post](http://zsprawl.com/iOS/2012/03/using-the-native-tabbar-plugin-in-cordova/) where few extra lines are added to avoid any conflict and it works!

Comment: I'll try this out. Thanks a lot! I'll post my results and select your answer if it works!

Comment: After testing the code in that post, it still didn't work out but I saw somewhere code such as: Cordova.exec("NativeControls.showTabBar", options);
    
    var onSelect = {"onSelect":onTabBarItem};
    //onSelect = "hahaha";

Comment: Cordova.exec("NativeControls.createTabBarItem", "test", "test", "tabButton:Recents", onSelect);
    Cordova.exec("NativeControls.createTabBarItem", "test2", "test2", "tabButton:Search", onSelect);
    Cordova.exec("NaviteControls.createTabBarItem", "test3", null, "tabButton:More", onSelect);
    
    Cordova.exec("NativeControls.showTabBarItems", "test", "test2", "test3"); 
    Cordova.exec("NativeControls.selectTabBarItem", "test");

Comment: And this seems to create the tab bar, but it's not very reliable. I don't like calling an execute function for every other function either. There must be a better way.

Comment: Also selecting the tabbaritems don't call the onTabBarItem function which I have defined in my javascript. So, I have a tabbar without functionality. Not very useful :(

Answer (score 4):

This is my code and it works:

```
function onDeviceReady()
{
  var nc = window.plugins.nativeControls;

  nc.createTabBar();
  nc.createTabBarItem('whoTabItem', 'Quem?', '', null);
  nc.createTabBarItem('whereTabItem', 'Onde?', '', null);
  nc.createTabBarItem('whatTabItem', 'O que?', '', null);
  nc.showTabBar();
  nc.showTabBarItems('whoTabItem', 'whereTabItem', 'whatTabItem');

}
```

At the very end of NativeControls.js, window.plugins.nativeControls is initialized so it should be OK:

```
if(!window.plugins)
  window.plugins = {};

 window.plugins.nativeControls = new NativeControls();
```

Your call to createTabBarItem has 5 parameters - it's only 4. Eliminate that fourth blank parameter and make a test. Maybe that's why your onSelect function is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define *nativeControls* as variable at the top of main.js file, then you can use it in this line, otherwise, the js will through exception about undefined variable

```
 nativeControls = window.plugins.nativeControls;
```